# Configure Jetty OSGi bundle for max number of connection

Tags: java, jetty, osgi, embedded-jetty, equinox

How do we configure an embedded Jetty OSGi Bundle to have a limited number of HTTP Connections. i.e. I want to limit the number of connections that clients can make with Jetty Server.  once the limit is reached, it should reject the connection requests.

Is it possible to do it via Configuration Admin service in OSGi?. Do we have a property that we can set on Jetty Bundle like http.port etc which we can use to limit the number of connections.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is such a property: http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-http-service.html#configuration-properties

However, a Servlet Filter that does this is quite trivial to write. With the Apache Felix whiteboard you trivially register it with the current Http Service, so it will work for others as well.

Comment: I am working on the Equinox implementation and we have been able to set the http.port etc from the java code and provide it to the jetty bundle via configAdmin service.available properties are here. 
http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fequinox%2Fhttp%2Fjetty%2FJettyConstants.html

There is a property called CUSTOMIZER_CLASS which i think can be used but i am not sure about its usage.Do you have an idea of using JettyCustomizer/JettConfigurator and modifying the connectors for an acceptQueueSize.pls guide on equinox

Comment: You can use the Apache Felix whiteboard and the Filter also on equinox. This IS OSGi after all (though it might depend on the jetty you're using since the filter is not standardized yet)

Comment: Hi,I believe ,the servlet filter suggestion that you gave can restrict/regulate number of requests. However, I need a strong control on the number of HTTP Connections that are opened by server for requests (since 1 connection can be used for multiple requests in case of persistent connections) and not requests.              Can we control Connections using a filter ? Could you guide me on how can we put a limit on the number of Connections at the Jetty level ?

Comment: Just check the remote host and remote port of the request. This makes it trivial to limit the # of connections. For Jetty you have to look at the source code.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [pax-web](https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/display/paxweb/Pax+Web) which uses Jetty as the underlying web server you could add a jetty-server.xml and configure it via this one.

Comment: we are not using pax-web. could you help on Equinox Implementation with an embedded jetty. I have been looking into JettyCustomizer that can be used to modify the connectors and set the acceptQueueSize. Do you have an idea on same?. I would want to do it via configAdmin service of OSGi and etting follwing properties http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fequinox%2Fhttp%2Fjetty%2FJettyConstants.html